# Parallelize a matmul-like matrix computation (tensor product) in Numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, tensor, numpy-einsum

I want to implement a tensor Tucker product s.t.,

- Input: `B` in shape `(m, n)`, `C` in shape `(n, n, n)` (cube).
- Output: `Y` in shape `(m, m, m)`, s.t. `Y_ijk = ∑_{0≤a,b,c<n} B_ia * B_jb * B_kc * C_abc`.

The raw for loop code:

```py
def raw_tensor_product(B, C, i, j, k):
    '''
    @param B: (m, n)
    @param C: (n, n, n)
    @param i: index in range(0, m)
    @param j: index in range(0, m)
    @param k: index in range(0, m)
    @return: the (i, j, k) entry of the product result Y
    '''
    m, n = B.shape
    return np.sum([B[i, a] * B[j, b] * B[k, c] * C[a, b, c] for a in range(n) for b in range(n) for c in range(n)])
```

Then how to write the equivalent code of above in numpy, which returns the `(m, m, m)` result `Y` directly? I tried something like `tensordot` and `matmul`.

Note that `C`'s dimension can be generalized. If it's `(n, n)`, then the result would be `B.dot(cube).dot(B.T)`. Also e.g., if it's `(n, n, n, n)`, the result would be an `(m, m, m, m)` tensor - then how to implement it?

And further, could you recommend some materials where I could learn such technologies? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way:

```py
np.tensordot(np.tensordot(np.tensordot(C, B, (0, 1)), B, (0, 1)), B, (0, 1))
```

But I'm not sure whether this would be the most efficient/elegent method.